# The use of words "granted" and "admittedly"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Tell me please if the word *granted* and *admittedly* mean the same in the following sentence.

> Kate wrote the poem, **granted**/**admittedly** her parents helped her a bit.

Comment: I would use a comma after granted/admittedly.

Comment: and a semicolon or dash or full stop before it.

Answer (score 2):

Most dictionaries treat "admittedly" and "granted" as identical in meaning. The implication is that what is being introduced weakens the argument or statement being put forward, but not so much as to invalidate it.

[Granted](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/granted)
[Admittedly](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/admittedly)

Comment: Some dictionaries give one of the words the simple meaning "admit or concede something", and give the other the additional nuance "when it weakens the argument", but they do not seem able to agree which way around this distinction should apply.